# how to program Java SWT app with one model and multiple views?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swt

I want a MVC pattern applied for a SWT application. I will only have one model, but three tables to present the model in three different aspects. And only one view is editable. When it is edited by user input, two others should be triggered to updated automatically. My question is:

1. Is my design appropriate? Should I divide the model into three to match three viewers?
2. If this design is ok, what technique can I apply to register three listeners for the model change?

Please give me some tips so that I could start my own experiment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The JTable api contains setModel and getModel methods

Comment: As well as a setEnabled method that could be used to disable the other two tables

Comment: @fdsa Sadly, the question isn't about `Swing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my design appropriate? Should I divide the model into three to match three viewers?

Yes to the first, no to the second. This is the same for any MVC approach: you shouldn't change your model depending on how it is going to be displayed.

However, SWT by itself doesn't support MVC particularly well. I recommend using JFace (an extension of SWT). JFaces tables are described pretty well in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html). You'll need to have one `ContentProvider` which references your model (assuming that each row in all three tables corresponds to one element of the model), and different `ColumnLabelProviders` for columns of your tables (alternately, a single `LabelProvider` per table).

For making the table editable, see http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am studying about content provider and label provider. It seems content provider has the ability of notifying model change. Hopefully that could solve my problem.